# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception on ionic build android

Tags: angularjs, cmd, ionic-framework

I am using ionic(1.7.12) in Ubuntu(64-bit), my project was working fine until i try to add splash screen to my project in resources file. and I try to do `ionic build android` then i am getting this error in my cmd.

```
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
AAPT: libpng error: Read Error
:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.357 secs
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /home/gopi/Desktop/Ionic-app/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/gopi/Desktop/Ionic-app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/gopi/Desktop/Ionic-app/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/gopi/Desktop/Ionic-app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

I am not familiar with cmd please help me what is wrong and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to build the app locally on your computer, you either need to install Android SDK (for your app Android version) or to work on a Mac (for your app iOS version).

An alternative is the PhoneGap Build service. They do have a free plan (1 private app, unlimited public apps) and I'm currently using it. No need to install anything on my PC.